# MOOC importance

Tags: beginner, education

My problem is that at our masters program we have already been taught **R, Statistics, Neural nets, Python (pandas, sklearn, etc)**. Also my master thesis is directly related to **Deep Learning** and **Computer Vision (PyTorch, Tensorflow)**.

Thus, i avoided entering MOOC on this topics.

Now i have free time to pass all the MOOCs.

But how much more important is the record about the MOOCs passed than just master program for job appliance in Data Science?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the knowledge of the concepts there is no point in doing the MOOCs again. Also, in job applications it is enough to show that you have learned the skills from somewhere (in your case, masters program). What is more important is how well you have learned those skills. This can be shown by doing projects based on your skills. So I suggest you to do more and more projects related to data science which can be added to your resume.

Also, if you know all these skills well, share your knowledge here on this platform!